# In Painless, remove value from array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

In Splunk SPL, it's easy to remove a value from an array....

| eval Account_Name = mvindex(Account_Name, 0)

Windows security logs reference the account name as the machine name in array(0)

array(1) contains the actual executing account name.

I need to do the same thing as the mvindex function in Painless.

I find lots of hits searching this but haven't found anything that works. THere must be a simple way to remove an array value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look for the following thing?

```php
POST sample_index/_doc
{
  "Account_Name": [
    "machine-name",
    "account-name"
  ]
}

POST sample_index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['Account_Name'].remove(0)",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}


GET sample_index/_search
```

The result after search :

```php
{
  "took": 892,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sample_index",
        "_id": "t3RIY4YBnUNkT6fHnBrI",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Account_Name": [
            "account-name"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error:

response:

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "index request with op_type=create targeting backing indices is disallowed, target corresponding data stream [logs-system.security-default] instead"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "index request with op_type=create targeting backing indices is disallowed, target corresponding data stream [logs-system.security-default] instead"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: Could you post the query in to question, you are executing?